Get a list of Vimeo videos by ID from API
I have a database that tracks video metadata for Vimeo videos, and thus I have a list of Vimeo video ids.
I want to efficiently refresh the metadata, so I'd like to fetch a (paginated) list of videos given a set of Vimeo ids.
This seems like a pretty standard API endpoint, but I don't see that it's possible in the
API docs.
Anyone know of a way to do this?
